# Equals method not returning the correct value

Tags: java, hashcode

I know the question that I am going to ask is very simple but I am a newbie to Java so I am finding it difficult.

I have overridden the hashCode and equals method in my class.

```
public class Hashing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1=new String("a");
        String s2=new String("b");
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now the Output should be "true" but is is always giving the output as false. Anyone Please explain.

Comment: You are executing `String`'s equals, not your class's `equals` implementation.

Comment: You are comparing two strings, not two `Hashing`s

Answer (score 2):

You have indeed created an `equals()` method, but it is for the `Hashing` class and not the `String` class.
Unfortunately you will not be able to override `String`'s `equals`/`hashCode` methods since it is a `final` class (cannot be subclassed and therefore overridden).

Comment: "Unfortunately"? I should say not. The havoc that would've ensued should `String` not have been final would have been egregious.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, s1 and s2 are objects of String class. So when you are writing s1.equals(s2), it is invoking equals method of the String class(whose implementation you can check via a decompiler).
You have provided overridden methods for class Hashing.

If you had written something like this, then the output would have been **true**

```
public class Hashing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // String s1=new String("a");
        // String s2=new String("b");
        Hashing s1=new Hashing();
        Hashing s2=new Hashing();
        System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
        // output -> true
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```